Difference between function in Azure web job and Azure Function
I am considering writing a queue-triggered function and find there are two ways, one is that I can create a Azure web job and add queue triggered function in the web job guidance here, another one is I can directly write a queue triggered Azure Function.
May I ask what the difference between these two ways? Seems they use the same web job SDK. The reason why I am asking here is that I read the Azure Function guidance, it suggests avoid long running functions. I am not sure whether it is the same for function in an Azure web job as well.
If it does, is there any better way to listen to queue and run long time jobs concurrently? Thanks!


There are many articles detailing the difference. However have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/webjobs-vs-azure-functions/
You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout for details on the timeouts for functions


Long-running Functions or Web Jobs should always be avoided, yes. You might be able to use the Durable Functions pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=in-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cv1-model

Azure WebJobs and Azure Functions both support queue-triggered processes using the same WebJobs SDK, but they differ in how they handle scaling and long-running tasks.
Best Approach for Long-Running Queue Processing would be using Durable Functions.
For more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create?tabs=windowscode
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=in-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cv1-model&pivots=csharp

